# how to save coordinates in C++

Tags: c++, coordinates

I have a matrix with cubes that have these colors: red, green, yellow.

Some of the cubes which are next to each other contact with others which are same color. For example:

```
  1 2 3 4 5
1 r r g y r
2 g y g g g
3 g y r g r
4 g g r g g
```

I want to count how many cubes with the same color are near to each other (in this example there are 7 g (green) cubes which are near to each other. This part I have already done.

```
bool Move(Cubes & Test, Cubes & Kub, int i, int j, int p, string color, int & count){
    int tt = 0;
    bool yra = false;
    if(Test.Get(i, j).GetCube(p) == Color){
        Test.SetSP(i, j, p, "-");
        count++;
        while(!yra && tt < 4 ){
            i = i + Test.GetEil(tt);
            j = j + Test.GetStu(tt++);
            if(Test.Get(i, j).GetCube(p) == color){
                Move(Test, Kub, i, j, p, color, count);
            }
        }
    }
    return yra;
}

void Max(int & count, int & max, string & s, string Spal[], int sp, Maximum Maxi[], int & ind, int i, int j){
    if(count!=0){
        Maxi[ind].Set(count, Spal[sp]);
        ind++;
    }
    if(max < count){
        max = count;
        count = 0;
        s = Spal[sp];
    }
    else
        count = 0;
}
```

And now somehow I need to save my green color coordinates which are near to each other.

What should I do to achieve that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "save"? Save to file?

Comment: I tried to correct the english, but I did not want to change what he means, so I left the parts I was'nt sure about. I did my best ;-) (but reading 'algorythm' was making by eyes bleed)

Comment: zmo sorry again :/ 
To Joachim I need to save coordinates in array

Comment: To PaF .GetCube(p) returns top of the cub. Move function check if cubes are near each other.

Comment: Any ideas how to do that? :/

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't normally explain what I need to do. But here's http://snag.gy/g5Fn4.jpg picture. Red cubes are near to each other and Move function check if cube with the specific color have a neighbour with the same color.

Comment: Ok as You can see from that picture red cubes are somehow connected with other red cubes. Their edge is side by side to other RED cubes. So somwhow I need to save coordinates of the same color cubes witch are side by side to other cubes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. somehow I need to fixed those coordinates.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure may help by the way.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I think you're trying to determine the **nearest square**, and **not** cube - as you're using two variables to keep track of `i` and `j`. Additionally, I can't comment accurately on your code as some details are missing.

So, since you've asked how to determine the nearest "cube"(sic) - i.e. square - this is something called a [Nearest Neighbor Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) - which is also known as the **Post-Office Problem** - the difficulty of which increases with dimensionality.

Nonetheless, examining your grid and making the assumption that we are limited to 2D:

[image: random grid of colored red, green and yellow squares]

We immediately observe that we can use regular Euclidean techniques to find the closest square relative to one:

[image: Euclidean nearest distance formula]

So if we know the coordinates of the each square, we can then calculate the distance to each from the current square in question.

EXAMPLE

Nearest neighbors of the yellow square on (row 1, col 4) (assuming a size of two for each side):

This sample grid has two other yellow squares `square1(2, 2)` and `square2(3, 2)`

If we assume that this grid is cartesian, with the bottom-left corner of green square (row 4, col 1) being centered at coordinate (1.0, 1.0) (remember we said that the sides were of length 2). Then, the center coordinates for:

```
yellow: (7.0, 7.0)
square1: (3.0, 5.0)
square2: (3.0, 3.0)
```

At this point you have to determine how you want to calculate the nearest square: **edgewise, or from center to center?**

Center to center is the easiest so, using yellow square at (row 1, col 4), the distances of the other squares relative to it (using the formula given) are:

```
yellow -> square1: sqrt(4^2 + 2^2) = sqrt(20) = 4.4721...
yellow -> square2: sqrt(4^2 + 4^2) = 4*sqrt(2) = 5.6569...
```

From these, we can clearly see that `square1` is closer to the yellow square (row 1, col 4).

1. So, one way to calculate those coordinates are to poll the grid for all squares of a different color, determine their respective coordinates.
2. Then, iterate over these coordinates (edgewise or center-wise) and determine which square has the smallest distance to a particular square in question.
3. Store the coordinates of the originating square and the closest square.
4. Repeat for all squares.

For more reading on this, you can consult:

http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~tgd/classes/534/slides/part3.pdf